# unpacking RFID data

Tags: python, pyserial, rfid

I've been trying to receive information through a simple serial reader from a RFID reader with this simple code

```
try:
    ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS2", 9600)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    sys.exit("Error connecting device")

while True:
    data = ser.readline()
    if data:
        print(data)`
```

And while it prints the data, it doesn't display it properly. I've been told that I need to unpack it but even if I am given the format of the data, I still don't understand what format I should give as parameter, or what var type each field should be.

Basically what I don't know is what to put in the function unpack(??, data).

This is the data format:

STX (02h) |
DATA (10 ASCII) |
CHECK SUM (2 ASCII) |
CR |
LF | 
ETX (03h)

Also, I am able to see the data displayed properly through the command line `hexdump -C /dev/ttyS2` but I haven't found the translation of hexdump -C (not just hexdump) in python.

Comment: So you are receiving data, but you don't know how to extract STX, DATA, etc from that?

Comment: `binascii.hexlify(data)`?

Comment: Exactly. @HeinWessels

Comment: I've tried your solution but it just doesn't display it properly. I need to display it in Canonical (-C) in order to extract the data I want from it. @KlausD.

Comment: You could show some effort converting the data representation, now that you have some pointers.